# Why use Retrofit with AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Few days ago when I tried to learn how to use Retrofit, I found some tutorials that says on some occassions, we should use ASyncTask together with Retrofit. This puzzles me because my impression was we use Retrofit to avoid using ASyncTask. And now I've understood Retrofit quite well (enough to use it and change all my ASyncTask codes to Retrofit), I still haven't find a good excuse or reason to use ASyncTask with Retrofit. Or am I missing anything here?

Btw I saw at least 3 different tutorials that mention on using Retrofit with ASyncTask, but I couldn't find it anymore. I could only find 1, http://karanbalkar.com/2014/12/tutorial-94-using-retrofit-for-android/

Comment: retrofit can work synchronously or asynchronously. using it synchronously (with asynctask) is a way of easily chaining calls that need to happen in sequence. (or you could use Rx for that.)

Comment: @njzk2, can you please provide a sample of chaining calls? Because I've never seen that... or maybe I have, but I may have overlooked...

Comment: consider 2 calls, where the arguments to the second one depend on the result from the first. That requires making those calls one after the other. Now, consider how you would do that using the callback-based version of your api calls, and consider how you would do that using the synchronous version in an asynctask. You should see that the asynctask version is much nicer. For extra points, do the same using the Rx version of the call.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks a lot for pointing that out! I have been doing that for years with ASyncTask that it was almost a routine, and I think that made me really forget what I was doing!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cited tutorial uses synchronous calls. For synchronous calls it makes sense to put them into an `AsyncTask`.

However, since Retrofit also supports asynchronous calls, it is easier to use them directly without an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I really thought AsyncTask is only used for asynchronous calls, hence the name AsyncTask. And from the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, the only time it mentions synchronous is in the line "AsyncTask guarantees that all callback calls are synchronized in such a way that the following operations are safe without explicit synchronizations." By the synchronous  calls you mentioned above, did u meant what the documentation says?

Comment: No, the retrofit call itself is synchronous, meaning it blocks until a response is received.

Comment: I understood that, but we can easily make retrofit asynchronous by specifying callback right? My comment above about the usage of ASycnTask for synchronous calls, as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Yes, the asynchronous calls with callback are the second part of my answer. For these you don't need an AsyncTask. But if you use the synchronous calls of retrofit (without a callback) you wrap them into an AsyncTask to make the whole thing asynchronous.

Comment: So my understanding now is we don't actually need ASyncTask, but we can also use it if we want. But why? I mean why bother making our life miserable, if Retrofit can achieve the same thing